# How to enable or disable functions in my app depending on fetched data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a profile for an app that requires some data to be fetched from Firebase database and then shown into the user profile.

So far, so good, this requirement is done and all the data is fetched correctly to the user profiles.

But now I have another requirement that put some of my functionality in a spot that I'm trying to figure out how to do it the better way.

I load all the data of the profile with this method (since it's a big method I'm going to shrink it, but the question is not about the code but about logic).

```
        private void loadProfileData() {
            if (mActivity == null) {
                return;
            }

            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mDatabase.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                        UserModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);

    String username = model.getUsername();
  .
  .
  .
     //All data loaded 

    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

...
```

So, while this data is being fetched I have an overflow menu that has the option to edit the user profile.

[image]

Now, that edit profile option is enabled while my data is beign fetched, and I need to pass extras to that Activity with all the user info that is fetched from Firebase in order to load it there and edit it.

Now, I have thought this in two ways

1. Wait until all async process is done and then enable the edit
   profile option in the navigation menu
2. Leave the menu button enabled while the data is being fetched and
   fetch it again when I'm inside that Activity (that would be
   reloading all the data instead of passing it as extra which will be
   more efficient) but at the same time I'm doing two requests for the
   same data

Is there any better way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to load all user data in the background, perhaps on app start? You can then display the edit button, and assume the current cache of data is correct.

You can still pull the latest copy of the data, and then update the UI accordingly *if* it's any different. I imagine the data won't change often however, so loading it a few minutes earlier is presumably safe.

Comment: yes, I thought this, and the thing is that the first Activity that the user see is the Profile one, so there is always the menu button, and disabling all the overflow or the edit profile button will kill some UX

Comment: Ah, so you *need* the profile data? Why not have a blocking progress spinner or similar then, since you don't want them interacting until you have at least *a* version of their profile data?

Comment: yep, I have a progressBar that shows at the start untill all the data is done fetching and then I show to the user all the data, but the thing is that the overflow menu is always there and I dont want it to be disabled untill the data is done fetching , I saw how instagram does this and its kinda like they preload the data at the start of the app and when you navigate to the profile section , all is done, but at my use case I start at the profile Activity

Comment: I don't suppose you can change the app's flow? Since (based on what you've said), the profile is first, and the profile needs data, what's wrong with disabling *all* interaction (including overflow) until it's done?

Comment: the problem there is that I see apps having that overflow enabled while the data is beign fetched, I cant change the flow since my client need it to be that way

Comment: Those other apps presumably don't have the profile as the first screen... For there to be a profile, presumably the user has to login at some point, right? Why not pull the user's data then?

Comment: thats a good idea Jake, but Imagine that loading a profile with images at the loading screen will maybe affect in the time of signing in, but I will take that advice since its a good workaround at the moment

Comment: The user has to wait either way, on login makes more sense (since they have to wait anyway). Anyway, this has become a design discussion, maybe ask a new question if you've got a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question Gastón. So to answer your questions:

> Wait until all async process is done and then enable the edit profile option in the navigation menu

In my opinion, this is the recommended way in which you can solve this. Wait for the data and then enable the button. Let's be honest, you cannot edit something that isn't available yet. So get the data, enable the button and let the user update his own profile.

> Leave the menu button enabled while the data is being fetched and fetch it again when I'm inside that Activity (that would be reloading all the data instead of passing it as extra which will be more efficient) but at the same time I'm doing two requests for the same data

There is no need to get the data twice. It will be a waste of bandwidth and resources. There is not a good practice to get data over and over again since you can reuse it.

Comment: Btw, I don't think that getting the data before is needed will be a good option because the user might edit his profile or might not. So creating extra requests to get some data that you might use it, isn't practical. IMHO, I don't get data untill I certainly need it.